# How to allow only apks those are signed with my platform keys in Android OS

Tags: android, apk, android-source

I am using custom AOSP for our product, android N. Right now I am building "user" mode. How to block the Apks which are signed with other platform keys?
It should only allow the APKs which are signed with only my platform keys.

Answer (score 0):

Modify PackageManger install methods to check apk signature and fail if it doesnt match the one you want.

Comment: http://androidxref.com/7.1.2_r36/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#4790

Comment: impl http://androidxref.com/7.1.2_r36/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java#1560

Comment: i will try this today and let you know the result thank you @rick Sanchez